# Negate a boolean based on another boolean

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

What's the short, elegant, bitwise way to write the last line of this C# code without writing `b` twice:

```
bool getAsIs = ....
bool b = ....

getAsIs ? b : !b
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you would do something like that? Just because of writing `b` twice? Performance? I don't think that any of those is a profound reason.

Comment: For brevity/readability and maybe performance since getting to 'b' in my case actually involves dereferencing three properties.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the VM/compiler will optimize this in any way (dereferencing as well as the instructions), but it would be interesting to be proven wrong. And bit twiddling is surely no gain for readability :D

Comment: I doubt the VM/compiler dereferences since that affects runtime behavior, but it would be interesting to be proven wrong.  Eliminating repetitive code is surely a gain for readability.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The truth table can be expressed as:

```
getAsIs    b    getAsIs ? b : !b
--------------------------------
0          0    1
0          1    0
1          0    0
1          1    1
```

The result can be expressed as:

```
result = (getAsIs == b);
```

Comment: Actually, I can reframe my problem in terms of this answer.  That is, I can rename 'getAsIs' to 'targetValue'.

Comment: PlusOne - Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 9):

Try using binary XOR ([^ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx)):

```
bool getAsIs = true;
bool b = false;

bool result = !(getAsIs ^ b);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's

```
var foo = !(getAsIs ^ b)
```

Short, elegant, but definitely a head-scratcher!